# mod_rewrite not redirecting to controller from subfolder(Symfony 2)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

Good day. 
I have the following structure in project:

```
/project
   ...
   /web
      /uploads
          .htaccess
          test.txt
      .htaccess // Symfony htaccess
```

I want to redirect all requests to `/uploads/test.txt` to a separate controller, which decides if the user have rights to read the `test.txt` file.

The content of `/web/uploads/.htaccess` is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^(.*)uploads/test.txt$ /app_dev.php/uploader/test [PT,L,QSA]
```

The problem is that this htaccess file is never redirecting requests to controller action (uploader/test points to right controller and action).
It just returns the `uploads/test.txt` file. The logs show that the file is simply passed through both with enabled/disabled PT flag.

```
[Mon Nov 16 07:40:40.823485 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 27811] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.142.1:61956] 192.168.142.1 - - [test.lh/sid#b6329d90][rid#b63fe058/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/web/uploads/] applying pattern '^(.*)uploads/test.txt$' to uri 'test.txt'
[Mon Nov 16 07:40:40.823500 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 27811] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.142.1:61956] 192.168.142.1 - - [test.lh/sid#b6329d90][rid#b63fe058/initial] [perdir /var/www/test/web/uploads/] pass through /var/www/test/web/uploads/test.txt
```

So, why it isn't redirecting to controller?

Comment: Have you checked that you don't have a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]` somewhere upstream of your `.htaccess` ? Like in your apache virtual host configuration ?

Comment: No, I haven't anything like that in vhost config. I have deleted .htaccess in subfolder and moved rewrite rule for 'test.txt' to the top of Symfony htaccess. Still not redirecting correctly.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR, if target file exists (rule points to the dir/file before rewriting), mod_rewrite ignores that rule. That definitely happens if you want to pass through `/dir` when you want to catch `/dir` by mod_rewrite. It's impossible, AFAIK.

Whatever - if you want to filter permissions, move the `upload` folder outside `web`.

Then: create a route with this structure and use: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#serving-files

This is the most reliable way to achieve this. So far, more and more people are moving rewriting rules directly to the application. And that's okay. Especially if your HTTPd has `X-Sendfile` support. Overhead is minimal then.